# How to Solve C Program Raises Malloc Error With Opened Files?

Tags: c, file, io, malloc

I have a program to read a file (given as a parameter in argv) line by line and output it to a different file. Here is the code;

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CAT_PREFIX_LEN    4
#define CAT_PREFIX        "bsh_"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *toread, *towrite;
    char *line;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    char catfile[CAT_PREFIX_LEN + strlen(argv[1]) + 1];

    // Opening file to read
    toread = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    // Create output file name
    strcpy(catfile, CAT_PREFIX);
    strcat(catfile, argv[1]);

    // Opening file to write
    towrite = fopen(catfile, "w");

    while((read = getline(&line, &len, toread)) != -1) {
        fprintf(towrite, line);
    }

    fclose(toread);
    fclose(towrite);
}
```

However if I try to run this program with a test file `test.txt` I get the error:
`convert_script(21115,0x7fffcb3f43c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10caca4c0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6`

I've tried multiple things; the first thing I tried was to comment out the whole for loop. If I do comment out the whole for loop, the error goes away. I also tried removing the opening, closing and writing to `test.txt`. If I remove it, the error also goes away. I don't really know what could be causing it. I am running it on a MacBook Air and compiling it using gcc to compile it.

Comment: How do you know your `fopen()` calls even work?

Comment: This is *probably* not the reason for your problems, but `fprintf(towrite, line);` is extremely poor style. If `line` constains things that look like formatters, very bad things can result. You probably meant something like `fprintf(towrite, "%s", line);`

Comment: Are you using C99?

Comment: Don't forget to `free (line);` as `getline` allocates memory for you -- you should always (1) preserve a pointer to the begging of the block (e.g. `line`) and (2) `free` the memory when it is no longer required. (yes it happens on exit, but building good habits now will pay dividends later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *line;
```

is not initialized and contains an indeterminate value.

The [Linux `getline()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) says

> If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` and `*n` is set `0` before the call, then
>          `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
>          should be freed by the user program even if `getline()` failed.

Since you're on a Mac, [the POSIX `getline()` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) adds this:

> **The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function.** If `*n` is non-zero,
>   the application shall ensure that `*lineptr` either points to an
>   object of size at least `*n` bytes, or is a null pointer.

For strict compliance with the POSIX standard, you should initialize `line` to `NULL`:

```
char *line = NULL;
```

Edit:  The official Apple [getline() man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getline.3.html) states:

> The caller may provide a pointer to a malloced buffer for the line in
>   `*linep`, and the capacity of that
>        buffer in `*linecapp`.  These functions expand the buffer as needed, as if via `realloc()`.  If `linep`
>        points to a `NULL` pointer, a new buffer will be allocated.  In either case, `*linep` and `*linecapp` will be
>        updated accordingly.

Comment: And a note about always visiting the man page for any function you use -- is always a good idea. `strcpy(catfile, CAT_PREFIX);` also invokes *Undefined Behavior* as `catfile` is likewise uninitialized. At minimum `*catfile = 0;` is needed after VLA initialization before calling `strcat`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I did check the man page but that one detail eluded me.

Comment: @ChristopherBerry don't overlook `catfile` initialization after declaration as noted above.